# ADODB Connection String not working in Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been developing an ASP.NET application. I want to integrate Classic ASP file(.asp) in this application.

In a .asp file I have to fetch data from SQL Server 2008 r2 database.
For this I have created db and rs object. I have passed ConnectionString in db.Open function. But I am getting no output for this code.

Following is my code

```
   set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

   db.Open "provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RMToday;Persist             Security Info=True;"


   set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   rs.Open "select * from RMToday.dbo.[Current]",db

   if not rs.EOF Then
     response.Write(rs("DayClosed"))
   End If
```

I have searched in stackoverflow.com and got some related questions, answer.

I can not understand the wrong in this code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put `Response.Write rs.RecordCount` just after `rs.Open` ? just to see how many records was returned in your query.

Comment: nothing is printed for response.write , when I add the line "db.Open("DSN=RMToday")" . I have checked that there exist data in Current table. I think the problem is in ConnectionString for the object db @Zam

Comment: try to change db provider from `provider=SQLNCLI10;` to `provider=SQLNCLI10.1;`. you told that using SQL2008R2.

Comment: btw, what OS you have? did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553554/connectionstring-issues-sql-server-2008-on-windows-2008 ?

Comment: I have changed from provider=SQLNCLI10; to provider=SQLNCLI10.1; but no effect. and I am on windows 7 OS. My SQL Server product version is 10.5.4

Comment: when to use SQLOLEDB instead of SQLNCLI, when to use Database instead of Initial Catalog in ConnectionString ? can you please clarify me and what else the problem of above code ? Thank you @Zam

Comment: you mean version MS SQL 10.50.4000.0 -- 2008R2 SP2. Full list: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Comment: Yes. Then what will be the solution of this problem ?