# ConnectionString not working when redirected to ASP page from ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a Report application in ASP.NET.

I have a previously developed Classic ASP Report application.

I want to load the ASP report file in ASPX page. 
I have kept the report files in a directory in ASP.NET application.

I am loading ASP report using following javascript method in "content" div in ASPX page:

```
$("‪#‎content‬").html('<object data="../ASPReports/Report1.asp"/>');
```

If my ASP page contains the following lines HTML is loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><% response.write("This line is printed")%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is when I Add the following line in my asp page[2nd line] no HTML is loaded:

```
set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

db.Open "provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Even the following declaration does not work:

```
Dim x
set x = 0
response.write(x)
```

I have tried changing the provider value to "SQLNCLI10.1". But still no output.

I am working in 
ASP.NET 4.0
SQL Server 2008 r2

Can anyone tell me the problem in this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use cookie for share data between ASP and ASP.NET

Comment: I have a previously developed Classic ASP application containing ASP files. I want to redirect user to one of these file when click on a link. ASP file contains database connection code. This connection code is not working. @Zam

Comment: Question related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206939/adodb-connection-string-not-working-in-classic-asp

no, i still don't have answer so far

Comment: That was my previous question. I have tried these solutions.

Comment: does everything (connection to SQL server) works fine from ASP.NET? issue only from ASP pages? does SQL server located on the same server where your web sites placed?

Comment: try this connection string :) `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<YourPassword>;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Packet Size=4096;`. sorry, that i still didn't give you information about connection string

Comment: Two common problems i see are, Have you tried enabling "Classic ASP parent paths" and  setting  -scriptErrorSentToBrowser:true    http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/security-is-painful

Comment: I didn't. I am getting no error when redirected to ASP page. Checked console output, Thanks

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason for the 0 vote after getting 1 vote ?